# Drawing chart.js with external JSON

Tags: javascript, json, charts, chart.js

I have this issue I can't seem to figuere out on my own. I am unable to draw a chart with chart.js with an external JSON file. When I console.log(data) the data it shows correctly, in an array, but nothing shows up on the canvas. I have managed to draw a chart with static JSON data using this code:

```
var myData2 = [

   {
 "name": "1. The Wolf of Wall Street",
    "gross": 116.901
   },
   {
    "name": "2. Frozen",
    "gross": 400.738
},
{
    "name": "3. RoboCop (1987)",
    "gross": 58.607
},
{
    "name": "4. Gravity",
    "gross": 274.092
},
{
    "name": "5. The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug",
    "gross": 258.366
},
{
    "name": "6. Thor: The Dark World",
    "gross": 206.362
},
{
    "name": "7. Captain America: The Winter Soldier",
    "gross": 259.766
},
{
    "name": "8. The Legend of Hercules",
    "gross": 18.848
},
{
    "name": "9. X-Men: Days of Future Past",
    "gross": 233.921
},
{
    "name": "10. 12 Years a Slave",
    "gross": 56.671
}
     ]
  Array.prototype.mapProperty = function(property) {
      return this.map(function (obj) {
       return obj[property];
      });

     };
 console.log(myData);  


// Example: myData.mapProperty('rank') to get an array of all ranks 
     lineChartData = {
        labels : myData.mapProperty('name'),
         datasets : [
           {
       label: "My First dataset",
       fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
       strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
       pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
       pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
       pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
       pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
       data : myData.mapProperty('downloads')
      }
           ]
      };
     lineChartData2 = {
        labels : myData2.mapProperty('name'),
         datasets : [
           {
       label: "My First dataset",
       fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
       strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
       pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
       pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
       pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
       pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
       data : myData2.mapProperty('gross')
      }
           ]
      };


window.onload = function()
{
 var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
 window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData);
 var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
 window.myLine2 = new Chart(ctx2).Line(lineChartData2);
}
```

However when I try and use the following code (with an external JSON) it doesn't doesn't draw a chart, but the console log shows that the array is exactly the same, without any other errors or issues.

```
 <script src="Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartCanvas">
     <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
     <br>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("js/dataverkeer.json",function(data){
      var myData = (data);

   Array.prototype.mapProperty = function(property) {
          return this.map(function (obj) {
           return obj[property];
          });

         };

          console.log(myData);
   // Example: myData.mapProperty('rank') to get an array of all ranks 
     lineChartData = {
        labels : myData.mapProperty('jaar'),
         datasets : [
           {
       label: "My First dataset",
       fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
       strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
       pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
       pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
       pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
       pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
       data : myData.mapProperty('verbruikInGB')
      }
           ]
      };


    window.onload = function()
    {
     var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
     window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData);
    }  




  });
</script>
```

And the external JSON

```
  [
      {
        "jaar": "1999",
        "verbruikInGB": 1074.44
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2000",
        "verbruikInGB": 1095.89
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2001",
        "verbruikInGB": 1117.88
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2002",
        "verbruikInGB": 1140.24
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2003",
        "verbruikInGB": 1163.02
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2004",
        "verbruikInGB": 1186.31
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2005",
        "verbruikInGB": 1210
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2006",
        "verbruikInGB": 1234
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2007",
        "verbruikInGB": 1259
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2008",
        "verbruikInGB": 1309.6
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2009",
        "verbruikInGB": 1387.5
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2010",
        "verbruikInGB": 1387.5
      },
      {
        "jaar": "2011",
        "verbruikInGB": 1415.24
      }
  ]
```

I really can't find the problem, hopefully someone here can see what my error is. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I messed around with it and got it working (at least for me)

The notable parts I changed were the ajax:

```
$.ajax({url:"data.json",dataType:"json"})
  .fail(function(){alert("Im a failure")})
  .done(function(data){
  var myData = (data);
```

and I took the end part out of the "window.onload", which wasn't neccesary since you'd already declared the canvas.

I guess I'll dump all the code I used

```
<script src="Chart.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartCanvas">
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <br>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({url:"data.json",dataType:"json"})
  .fail(function(){alert("Im a failure")})
  .done(function(data){
  var myData = (data);
  console.log(myData[0].jaar);
Array.prototype.mapProperty = function(property) {
      return this.map(function (obj) {
       return obj[property];
      });

     };

// Example: myData.mapProperty('rank') to get an array of all ranks 
 lineChartData = {
    labels : myData.mapProperty('jaar'),
     datasets : [
       {
   label: "My First dataset",
   fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
   strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
   pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
   pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   data : myData.mapProperty('verbruikInGB')
  }
       ]
  };

 //window.onload = function(){
console.log("cheerio")
 var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
 window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData);
 //}
```

});